# Most efficient way to install multiple printers programmatically

Tags: c#, python, com, printing, automation

So I work in IT at work, and I'm trying to automate some routine stuff. We have about 5 printers and I'd like to write a script that will install all of them.

What would be the best way to do this? What would probably be the easiest language/library? I'm fairly competent in Python, PHP and Javascript (not ideally suited for this, obviously) and I've worked for a little bit in C# (very minimally, and mostly asp.net stuff), but I'm not against picking up/working in another language to try to implement this feature.

From what I'm seeing, my two main options are either running a shell operation with, say, rundll printui, or possibly using COM objects (my knowledge on COM is limited). Are there any other effective ways?

Sorry if this question has some subjectivity to it - if anyone would like, I'm happy to provide pseudocode of what I'm trying to write. I'm also happy to improve the question - I'm trying not to be overly broad, but even after some research my understanding of implementation is still incomplete.

EDIT: Note, this is mostly for Windows Vista and 7. We have one or two machines running XP, but they're non-critical and if need be, can be done manually.

Answer (score 1):

Most IT guys would probably use PrintUI via VBScript or something (along with Group Policy tricks), but there is no reason you can do the same in Python.

A couple of good reasources for print management using PrintUI:

[Command Line Printer Control](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/2kprintcontrol.php)

[Bruce's Printing Pages](http://members.shaw.ca/bsanders/FAQPrinting.htm)

In Python you would simply use `subprocess` or similar to make the calls.

As a very simple example, to map a network print residing on a print server somewhere:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(r'RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /gd /c\\computername /n\\printservername\printer')
```

Answer (score 0):

On a windows system I believe you can just use Print Migrator ([XP](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25311), [Vista](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753109%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)). Not quite as general-purpose as writing your own script, but probably a lot easier.

Comment: Eh, possibly, though I don't think this is probably TOO difficult of a task. I'm guessing about 3-4 hours after I truly understand what question I am trying to solve. I'll check that out though, but still want a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

late, but maybe can help a for a part of answer... if you are using .inf file. In this case is for a local printers,

**>>>> To do this without any wizard, the driver must be signed.**

**Windows 7**:

INSTALLATION:

- First Command install: `RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /if /b "Printer name" /f "driver.inf" /r "com1" /m "driver model name" /h "Intel"`
- Second Command set default printer: `RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "Printer name"`
- For installation you need just one command. Can change the "com1" if you are using usb, chose the most commom "usb001".

UNINSTALL:

To uninstall a printer you need 3 commands and strict follow the sequence:

1. The first, you need to remove all printers with that name that you can see in "device and printers": `RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /dl /n "Printer Name" /h "Intel"`
2. The second command is to remove the printer driver: `RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /dd /m "driver model name" /h "Intel"` . After this you cannot see the printer and the driver, but if you unplug the usb devide and plug again the driver will automatically install. this because windows add the driver installation pack to `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository` and we need to uninstall it with the third command.
3. The third command will remove the oem*.inf that is create by windows when install a driver. To complete this task you need 2 commands, the first is to search what the name of oem*.inf the windows creted for you: use this `pnputil.exe -e` to show all oem*.inf and with the name in hands use this `pnputil.exe -f -d oem5.inf` (change the name of the oem5.inf to correspond to you inf file)

I did thoses taks programmatically using C and Visual C++6 - with this commands, except to search the oem*.inf name that you need to parse all .inf files under `C:\Windows\Inf\`. Another parameter to automate is use /q to run in without notification to user.

There is a behavour that you need care when using cli to install... do not execute two installation for the same printer, windows will create a random name like you install printer B and windows will rename to printer B (copy_A) or something else if the printer B already exist. And if you need to uninstall you will need to remove the two printers before going to the second command to uninstall the driver.

For remote printers you need to change the paramters, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057.aspx

Also see the code about devcon https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/DevCon-Sample-4e95d71c